# How to ensure that `setState` called sequentially inside async useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that makes an API request to retrieve data from backend. The request has several dynamic parameters. If one of the parameters is changed then the API call repeats to retrieve new data.

Example:

```js
const Component = ({dep1, dep2}) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  const getData = async () => {
    const data = await api.getData({dep1, dep2});
    setData(data);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, [dep1, dep2])

  return <div>{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>
}
```

So my problem is that i have this situation:

1. `dep1` is changed, **first request** is sent
2. `dep2` is changed, **second request** is sent
3. **second request** finished first, `setState` is called first time.
4. **first request** finished second, `setState` is called second time.

So in the end i have data from the first request in my current state...
How can i avoid that? How to call `setState` in the same order that my requests are sent and not in the order of received responses?

Thank you

Comment: `AbortController` to abort the request, or use something like `react-query` that handles this for you. or even a variables that tracks whether the response should be discarded or not

Comment: *"How to call setState in the same order that my requests are sent ..."* Is that really what you want, or do you just want to avoid stale responses calling `setData` (that's simpler)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume you don't really need the calls to be in order, but instead you just don't want an earlier call's result to overwrite a result from a later call.

There are at least a couple of different ways to do it.

1. Use an [`AbortController`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController) and abort it when the deps change; ideally, update `api.getData` so it use the `AbortController`' `AbortSignal` (for instance, it could pass it to `fetch` if it uses `fetch`). Here's an example — I moved `getData` into the `useEffect` as there's no need to recreate the function every time:

   ```
   const Component = ({ dep1, dep2 }) => {
       const [data, setData] = useState(null);

       useEffect(() => {
           const controller = new AbortController();
           (async function getData() {
               const { signal } = controller;
               try {
                   // Get the data; if it supports accepting and respecting an `AbortSignal`, pass it
                   // the abort signal (if it doesn't, add that if you can)
                   //                                     vvvvvvvv
                   const data = api.getData({ dep1, dep2 }, signal);
                   // If the call hasn't been aborted, save the data
                   if (!signal.aborted) {
                       setData(data);
                   }
               } catch (error) {
                   if (!signal.aborted) {
                       // ...handle/report errors...
                   }
               }
           })();
           // In the cleanup function, abort any in-progress request
           return () => {
               controller.abort();
           };
       }, [dep1, dep2]);

       return <div>{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>;
   };
   ```

   By making the `AbortSignal` available to `getData`, you may be able to prevent work involved in getting the data that would be wasted because of a newer call. But the above works even if for some reason you can't make `getData` abortable.
2. Use a sequence counter and only save the data if the counter matches the value you had when you started the request. You can track the counter in a [ref](https://react.dev/learn/referencing-values-with-refs) so that the current value of it is accessible inside `getData`.

   ```
   const Component = ({ dep1, dep2 }) => {
       const [data, setData] = useState(null);
       // Use a ref to track a sequence number for calls to `setData`.
       const setDataRef = useRef(0);

       const getData = async () => {
           // Increment the counter and remember it
           const sequenceNumber = ++setDataRef.current;
           try {
               const data = await api.getData({ dep1, dep2 });
               // Only save the resulting data if nothing has incremented the counter.
               // This works because the ref is stable and always refers to the  same
               // object, so we'll see the current `current` value.
               if (sequenceNumber === setDataRef.current) {
                   setData(data);
               }
           } catch (error) {
               if (sequenceNumber === setDataRef.current) {
                   // ...handle/report error...
               }
           }
       };

       useEffect(() => {
           getData();
       }, [dep1, dep2]);

       return <div>{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>;
   };
   ```

Other things being equal, I'd use #1, even if I couldn't update `getData` (but particularly if I could).